# WordPress - Page Name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in WordPress. I installed plugin "html-on-pages". This plugin add ".html" after page name in URL.

I added some pages in my WordPress project.

I want to remove '.html' in some conditions for some pages. I try to get name of page using $wp_rewrite of WordPress but not found any way.

Please suggest any way that return name of page or any function of WordPress that will return name of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$page_name = basename(get_permalink());
```

Comment: It work normally. Actually I am checking some conditions in php file of installed plugin. Here page name checked by "$wp_rewrite->page_structure". When I print it, got blank result.